# Get alpha float from a vec4 in OpenGL ES Shading Language

Tags: opengl-es

This may sound stupid, but I'm not quite sure how to get the "W" component itself from an inputted vec4.  I read in the spec that you cannot get individual components, so maybe it's just wrong to even ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can calculate dot product. So just multiply by another vec4 containing (0,0,0,1).

EDIT: however, are you sure you can't simply use .w? All the docs and examples I found say you can.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may have misread the spec — it's completely valid to read individual components. GLSL even allows implicit permutations and combinations of the original components, e.g.

```
lowp vec4 someVector;

// someVector.xy is a lowp vec2 containing the first two scalars from someVector
// someVector.zwx is a lowp vec3 containing the third, fourth and first scalars in that order
// someVector.w is a lowp float containing the fourth scalar
```

For example, I've used the fragment shader:

```
void main()
{
    lowp vec4 srcPixel = texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying);
    lowp vec4 yuvPixel = rgbToYuv * srcPixel;

    yuvPixel.r *= 3.0;

    gl_FragColor = yuvToRgb * yuvPixel;
}
```

With suitable matrices and varyings to boost the brightness of a texture three-fold.